# navigation MenuItem in toolbar doesn't trigger onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I'm trying to use the navigation drawer with toolbar, but pressing the navigation button doesn't trigger the onOptionsItemSelected handler and the list doesn't open.

Search button, however, trigger onOptionsItemSelected.

This is my code and xml:

**EDIT:**
also onDrawerClosed() and onDrawerOpened() aren't called

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

mAdapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles, numOfTabs);

// Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

// Assigning the Sliding Tab Layout View
mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

mTabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
    @Override
    public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
        return getResources().getColor(R.color.augury_white);
    }
});

// Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);

// Set navigation drawer
mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

// Set the adapter for the list view
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
// Set the list's click listener
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            mToolbar , R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            syncState();
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            syncState();
        }
    };

// Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

}

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <com.augury.mobile.auguryandroid.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/augury_blue"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you override `onPostCreate()`?

Comment: yes,  I called it with :  mDrawerToggle.syncState();

Comment: `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);` you have?  and what import for `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, V7?

Comment: I added mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true); - no change.

Comment: also have this - import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

Comment: I suppose your layout problem, so try my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   >

   <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
   >

  <include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

  <com.augury.mobile.auguryandroid.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/augury_blue"/>

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect!! thank you!!!  the only problem now is that the list view is too high and when its open you can't see the navigation arrow icon..

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.augury.mobile.auguryandroid.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:background="@color/augury_blue"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

write this

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

just after you set your toolbar

and remove

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

this will take you to previous task if you have any which might give you an unexpected behavior