# Getting an error using ScrimInsetFrameLayout

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, toolbar, material-design

I'm using [ScrimInsetsFrameLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java) to get the `Navigation Drawer` on the `ToolBar` with the `StatusBar` on it so I followed the guide and read a lot about it but there's something wrong even if I'm not missing anything.

Whenever I click one (of the four) activity in the `drawer_listView` or the `ic_drawer` the app force closes without messages in the `Logcat`.

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ListView mDrawerList;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
String[] mDrawerListItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryDark));
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mDrawerListItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_list);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDrawerListItems));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            openFragment(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close){
        public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View v){
            super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

protected void openFragment(int position){

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, WIND.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, GEO.class));
            break;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, COMPASS.class));
            break;
        case 3:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, BARO_ALTI.class));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home: {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
            return true;
        }
        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

`my_activity.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame">

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<beta_toolbox.pier.beta_toolbox.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:insetForeground="#4000">

    <ListView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:divider="#ffffffff"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

</beta_toolbox.pier.beta_toolbox.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>
```

My problem is limited to `my_activity.xml`. 
Please help me I can't go on with my project.

**[Update]**

I made my layout exactly like he did https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/activity_map.xml but **why I'm not getting the same result?!
**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<beta_toolbox.pier.beta_toolbox.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:insetForeground="#4000">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

</beta_toolbox.pier.beta_toolbox.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>

<ListView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:divider="#ffffffff"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Your `my_activity.xm` has problem. Try my answer for the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363085/navigation-menuitem-in-toolbar-doesnt-trigger-onoptionsitemselected/29363848#29363848)

Comment: @Xcihnegn How could I get the effect in the image above if I don't have _.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout_?

Comment: I did not say you remove that, just modify your layout based on my answer

Comment: @Xcihnegn I modified it based on your answer but in your way the drawer is under the ToolBar

Comment: Change the filter of the logcat to No filter and see the error.

Comment: Actualy the drawer is below the ToolBar, it should be I suppose, then you can click drawer icon, otherwise you only can use swipe when drawer open

Comment: Please post you MainActivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` just under `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`

Now you should be able to click on the `ic_drawer` to open the `drawer_layout`.

( you won't be able to click on an activity of that list, I'll try to get that issue. I'll update my answer tomorrow)

**Edit:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ListView mDrawerList;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
String[] mDrawerListItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryDark));

    mDrawerListItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_list);

    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDrawerListItems));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            openFragment(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close){
        public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View v){
            super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

protected void openFragment(int position){

    Intent intent;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
            break;
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
            break;
        case 3:
            intent = new Intent(this, Activity4.class);
            break;
        default:
            intent = null;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
    //mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);    

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home: {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
            return true;
        }
        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually yes, it has the effect I was looking for. I'll wait for the update

Comment: Sorry mate, I was busy for my work. Check the edit and just replace

Answer (score 1):

make windowActionBar to true in the styles
Try this and the navigation should go under

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >      

 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>

</LinearLayout>

<beta_toolbox.pier.beta_toolbox.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
   android:layout_width="304dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="start"
   app:insetForeground="#4000">

  <ListView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:divider="#ffffffff"
    android:dividerHeight="8dp"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:scrollbars="none"/>

</beta_toolbox.pier.beta_toolbox.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[**UPDATE**]

According to Android doc:

```
public void  syncState ()
```

This should be called from your Activity's onPostCreate method to synchronize after the DrawerLayout's instance state has been restored, and any other time when the state may have diverged in such a way that the ActionBarDrawerToggle was not notified. (For example, if you stop forwarding appropriate drawer events for a period of time.)

So can you try to remove all your others of call `syncState()`

Comment: I copied and pasted it but I still cannot click neither the drawer nor the drawable. Anyway the ND is under the toolbar when I open it

Comment: just modified layout again, can you try, better copy all

Comment: Still error D: ...but are you trying on a project of your own?

Comment: Yes I am trying with my own project, its working fine

Comment: But my project not using `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout`

Comment: Do you use a library?

Comment: You mean support library? yes V7, and ToolBar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74866/discussion-between-rick-and-xcihnegn).

Comment: @Rick is you give the answer downvote, why? if you do not like my solution, just forget it, I just try to solve your issue