# how to add DrawerLayout to my mainActivity.xml in android

Tags: android, fragment, drawerlayout

Now my mainActivity.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#FFFFFF"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/title_bar" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/tab_content"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1" />

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this page has four tabs on the bottom,each tab is associated with a different fragment which will be added to android:id="@+id/tab_content".

**Here is my questions,how to add DrawerLayout to the mainActivity.xml and only allow the first fragment to open the drawer layout.**

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363085/navigation-menuitem-in-toolbar-doesnt-trigger-onoptionsitemselected/29363848#29363848)

Comment: Thanks for your recommended post ,but the solution allow all the tabs to have DrawerLayout feature? And I only need the first fragment to open drawer layout.